# ActiveMQ filter multiple log line on console

Tags: activemq-classic

I embedded activeMQ on my JavaEE 8 (Liberty 18) application .
My own activeMQ filter wrote multiple line of log in console .
This is my example code :

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends BrokerFilter {
public AuthenticationFilter(Broker next) {
    super(next);
}

@Override
public void addConnection(ConnectionContext context, ConnectionInfo info) throws Exception {
    String username = info.getUserName() ;
    String password = info.getPassword() ;
    if (username.equals("EXAMPLE_USER_NAME") && password.equals("EXAMPLE_PASSWORD")) {
        System.out.println("Authentication Success .");
        super.addConnection(context, info);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Authentication Failed for clientID : " + info.getClientId());
        throw new SecurityException();
    }
}
}
```

and this example console output peer request .

```
Authentication Failed for clientID : 1112
Authentication Failed for clientID : 1112
```

two console line peer request ! . I also used logger or log4j but not fixed .
How can fix this ?

Comment: Only you can debug your own code.

Comment: why vote down ? I try to fix this problem but not fixed , I think this is a bug man .